# Why do my inner joins not work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is an embarassing question to ask! But I have not used tsql for some time now.

I have 3 tables:

- Job
- Gallery
- JobWorkUnit

The primary key of `Gallery` is linked to the corresponding foreign key in `Job`. The primary key of `JobWorkUnit` is linked to the corresponding foreign key in `Job`

I wish to return all the records on `Job` regardless of whether they have 'links' in the other 2  tables.

I had thought that using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the way to do it but I get no records returned at all.

Can someone please check my code?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Job J
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Gallery G ON G.JobRef = J.JobRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    JobWorkUnit JWU ON J.JobRef = JWU.JobRef
WHERE 
    J.Active = 1 
    AND G.Active = 1 
    AND JWU.Active = 1 
    AND J.CompanyRef = @CompanyRef
```

There are no records in `WorkUnit` or `Gallery`

If I remove:

```
AND G.Active = 1 
AND JWU.Active = 1
```

I get 2 records back so my `Where` clause is overriding my join type. Is that a fair thing to say?

Comment: Are there definitely any rows in `job`? Do you have a `where` clause? Why does the title ask about inner joins?

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for your comment. yes there are definatley rows in Job :). I have tested it without using the joins and I get 2 records back

Comment: but, I did have a Where cause and it is that that is th eproblem so Iwill edit my question. thanks for making me focus :)

Comment: If you have no rows in `JobWorkUnit` and `Gallery`, then any rows that are returned from `Job` will have all `NULL` for the columns of those two tables - requiring `G.Active = 1` will **not match** any of those rows - therefore, those rows are discarded. You *could* change this to `WHERE (G.Active IS NULL OR G.Active = 1)` to include those rows that aren't returning any columns from the `G` table

Comment: @marc_s thanks. I should have concluded that as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a question of style/clarity, but I prefer not to filter data in join conditions. I'd rewrite your query thus:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
    Job J
Left OUTER JOIN Gallery G 
ON
     G.JobRef = J.JobRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN JobWorkUnit JWU
ON
     J.JobRef = JWU.JobRef
WHERE 
    J.Active = 1 
AND
    (G.Active = 1 OR G.Active IS NULL)
AND
    (JWU.Active = 1 OR JWU.Active IS NULL)
AND
    J.CompanyRef = @CompanyRef
```

Personally, I think that expresses the intent of the query most clearly.

**Edit:**
Just realised that no one has actually explicitly explained *why*.

When you do an outer join, the fields of the outer-joined table are null when there's no join. If you then use those fields in the `WHERE` clause, they will fail all filter criteria (except `IS NULL` of course) as happens with null values.

Comment: just got back. thanks for your answer. please give me a few minutes to digest. thanks :)

Comment: And with this query you are successfully not using possible indexes. Better combine those with `or Active is null`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I think your comment swung it for me here

Answer (score 5):

You should move filtering to join conditions, other way you are just filtering out rows with nulls:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Job J
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Gallery G ON G.JobRef = J.JobRef
                                     AND G.Active = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN JobWorkUnit JWU ON J.JobRef = JWU.JobRef
                                           AND JWU.Active = 1
WHERE   J.Active = 1
        AND J.CompanyRef = @CompanyRef
```

Comment: just got back. thanks for your answer. please give me a few minutes to digest. thanks :)

Comment: I had not even realized I can do this.

Comment: I now got to decided whether to put the filtering in the join or where and I am not sure. I will accept an answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

This query will return zero results only if the `job` table is empty

**UPDATED**: to show `where`

```
SELECT *
FROM Job J
    left join Gallery G ON J.JobRef = G.JobRef 
        and G.Active = 1
    left join JobWorkUnit JWU on J.JobRef = JWU.JobRef
        and JWU.Active = 1
where J.Active = 1 
    and J.CompanyRef = @CompanyRef
```

Comment: just got back. thanks for your answer. please give me a few minutes to digest. thanks :)

Comment: I had not even realized I can do this.

Comment: I now got to decided whether to put the filtering in the join or where and I am not sure. I will accept an answer as soon as I can